# Correct terminology for a table which provides "dynamic columns"

Tags: design-patterns, database-design, terminology, sql, sql-server

A common pattern in database design is to append dynamic columns to a table with a design like so:

```
create table MasterTable
(
    Id int not null primary key 
    , Name nvarchar(64) not null unique
    , SomeColumn2 int not null
)

create table MasterTableAdditionalColumn
(
    Id int not null primary key 
    , ColumnName nvarchar(64) not null unique   
)

create table MasterTableAdditionalColumnData
(
    Id int not null primary key
    , MasterTableId int not null foreign key references MasterTable(Id)
    , MasterTableAdditionalColumnId int not null foreign key references MasterTableAdditionalColumn(Id)
    , Value nvarchar(1024) not null
)

create unique index UK_MasterTableAdditionalColumnData_Key
    on MasterTableAdditionalColumnData 
    (
        MasterTableId
        , MasterTableAdditionalColumnId
    )
```

i.e. A design whereby we can effectively add a new `nvarchar(1024)` column to our `MasterTable` at any time by creating a new entry in `MasterTableAdditionalColumn` for the column name; and can populate this columns values by creating entries in `MasterTableAdditionalColumnData` with the appropriate column's Id (`MasterTableAdditionalColumnId`) and the related master record's Id (`MasterTableId`).

Is there a name for this pattern / type of table?  I've always used names like `dynamic columns` or `extension table`, but haven't had any luck finding those terms or anything official on Google.

---

#### Update

An example of what I'm referring to can be seen here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0a911/2

i.e. columns `Surname` and `JobTitle` in the result set get their values from a list of name-value pairs for each `MasterTable` record; i.e. from the `MasterTableAdditionalColumnData` table.

I'm wondering what the term for a table such as `MasterTableAdditionalColumnData`; or this approach to designing the data model to allow columns to be defined at run time is.

Comment: This is common?  Can you provide some evidence of that claim?  I'm not a DB guy per se but I'm not familiar with this.  I'm not actually sure exactly what you are saying.  Are you actually adding columns or are you talking about static structure that is used like an equivalent dynamic table structure?

Comment: @JimmyJames without knowing the term it's hard to search for, but I've seen this approach used in a number of off-the-shelf products as well as having used it myself.  Here's an SO post where someone's used a similar approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7448453/sql-server-pivot-vs-multiple-join/7449213#7449213

Comment: I have a sense that you are talking about a [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) but I'm still not sure exactly what you are describing.

Comment: This doesn't physically add columns to the table; rather it allows "virtual columns".  i.e. See this example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0a911/2

Comment: It's not normalization; though I can see why you'd suspect that.  This design is typically used to provide customization options; i.e. a product gives you all the columns the vendor expects you to need, but allows you to add on your own columns without having to amend their database's schema by allowing you to append meta data / name-value pairs to records in certain tables via these "dynamic column tables".

Comment: "User-Defined Columns."  I know you're trying to find a good Google term, but that's all this is.  See https://martinfowler.com/bliki/UserDefinedField.html

Comment: Thanks @RobertHarvey; great link.  It seems Martin's term for the database structure for persisting user defined fields is [attribute table](http://wiki.c2.com/?AttributeTable).

Answer (score 4):

**Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV) Model** seems to be the term I was looking for.  Here's the [Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model#Structure_of_an_EAV_table) on the topic.

It seems most people advise against this pattern, but as with everything it's about context / weighing up pros and cons for the scenario being used.

Here's a balanced blog post with some additional discussion around the pattern: https://sqlblog.org/2009/11/19/what-is-so-bad-about-eav-anyway

**Attribute Table** is an equally valid answer.  Thanks to @RobertHarvey for pointing me in this direction in the comments.

Here's a [blog post](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/UserDefinedField.html) by Martin Fowler on this, and a related [wiki article](http://wiki.c2.com/?AttributeTable).

Comment: The edit to your question doesn't really describe EAV.  EAV is used when there can be arbitrarily many different attributes, but only a few of those attributes (arbitrarily chosen) will have a value for a given entity.  The Wikipedia article explains this using a physician example, where a patient can have a few arbitrarily-chosen symptoms from a large list of possible symptoms.  None of this really has anything to do with adding columns to a table; it's essentially a collection of key-value pairs.

Comment: @RobertHarvey agreed that the usage I described differs slightly; i.e. sparse/one-off columns per row vs custom columns; but the term for the implementation was what I was after (I admit that term may change depending on context; but I had the implementation in mind rather than the problem to be solved when asking).